# Why variable is unresolved if there is an instance of it?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Why is this variable unresolved if there is an instance that we transwer into the function?
Could anyone help me with it?

```
Vue.component('university-row', {
    props: ['university', 'editMethod'],
    template: 'Templates'
    methods: {
        edit: function () {
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>this.editMethod(this.university);<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
        }
    }
});

Vue.component('university-list', {
    props: ['universities'],
    data: function() {
        return {
            university: null
        }
    },
    template: 'Templates',



    methods: {
        editMethod: function() {
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>this.university = university;<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<This one is unresolved
        }
    }
});
```

the second component has

````
        universityApi.get().then(result =>
            result.json().then(data =>
                data.forEach(university => this.universities.push(university))
            )
        )
    },```
````

Comment: Did you mean `editMethod: function() {` to be `editMethod: function(university) {`?

Comment: The two components do not share an instance and therefore do not know about function declarations defined in each other.